# Use Enum in Separate Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a method to implement a bank account. It's very simple, I want the output to be the name and account type of the user. However, I am having trouble using `Enum` in my main class.

```
from enum import Enum

class AccountType(Enum):
    SAVINGS = 1
    CHECKING = 2

#bank account classes that uses AccountType
class BankAccount():
    def __init__(self, owner, accountType):
        self.owner = owner
        self.accountType = accountType

    def __str__(self):
        self.d = AccountType(1)
        return "The owner of this account is {} and his account type is: {} ".format(self.owner, self.d)

#test the code
test = BankAccount("Max", 1)
print(test)
```

Output

`The owner of this account is Max and his account type is: AccountType.SAVINGS`

So this is the desired output, but this only works when I hard-code the account type in the `__str__` method (`AccountType(1)`). To clarify, I mean this line:

```
BankAccount("Max", 1)
```

Is there a way to do this such that if I enter `1` into the `BankAccount` parameter for accountType , it returns

`The owner of this account is Max and his account type is: AccountType.SAVINGS`

Comment: Why are you using `self.d` instead of `self.accountType`?

Comment: Unlcear what you meant by "if I enter 1 into the `BankAccount` object, it returns the account type?". Please [edit] your question and clarify—maybe with an example of what you want to happen.

Comment: @martineau. Thanks for the heads up. I've put my edit back but without the highlight.

Comment: Workhorse: Sorry, but your edit really didn't help much because you haven't said what you want to return that (string?) which looks exactly like what was shown earlier below "Output".

Comment: @martineau. Agreed. I like the block notation, but apparently OP does not. I'm mostly after the edit-and-answer within 12 hours badge.

Comment: Workhorse: You can get the name associated with an Enum value like this: `AccountType(1).name` -> `SAVINGS`. Does that help?

Comment: @martineau thanks for your response! Sorry, I am new to python. Where exactly would I input that line?

Comment: Workhorse: I think the problem is you saying that you're getting the desired output, but that's only because you've hardcoded something in the `__str__()` method—which wouldn't work for other account types, obviously. Check out the answer just I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess because I'm still unsure about exactly what you're asking.

```
from enum import Enum

class AccountType(Enum):
    SAVINGS = 1
    CHECKING = 2

#bank account classes that uses AccountType
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, owner, accountType):
        self.owner = owner
        self.accountType = accountType

    def __str__(self):
        return("The owner of this account is {} "
               "and his account type is: {} ".format(
                    self.owner, AccountType(self.accountType).name))

#test the code
test = BankAccount("Max", 1)
print(test)
test2 = BankAccount("Mark", 2)
print(test2)
```

Output:

```
The owner of this account is Max and his account type is: SAVINGS
The owner of this account is Mark and his account type is: CHECKING
```

This way you don't have to hardcode anything or create the `self.d` attribute since it's no longer needed.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! the ```.name``` command is new to me.

Comment: Workhorse: Truthfully, it's new to me, too. Each _member_ of an `Enum` has `name` and `value` attributes associated with it. The only explicit mention I've found about this in the documentation is in the last bullet point in this note about [Nomenclature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum)—so it's something that could be easily overlooked.

Comment: Workhorse: Correction: `name` and `value` are actually properties (not attributes) of members. There is a [little more about them](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same thing you do to the hard-coded 1 in `__str__` to `accountType` in `__init__`:

```
self.accountType = AccountType(accountType)
```

Even though you can now get rid of `self.d` and use `self.accountType`, I would recommend not using the integer value in the initialization to begin with:

```
test = BankAccount("Max", AccountType.SAVINGS)
```

This is much clearer than using a magic number. The update to `__init__` will accept both the enums and their values.

Comment: Is there a way to type in: